# Quadratic enhancements of the intersection form and spin structures

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, spin-geometry, cobordism

If we search [spin structures and quadratic enhancements of the intersection form](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&hs=iKR&sxsrf=ALeKk02oCxIG_AOp6HEd8sD0Z7DMthv19Q%3A1606422241646&ei=4Q7AX-z9Jo-YwbkPrp2akAU&q=spin+structures+and+quadratic+enhancements+of+the+intersection+form+&oq=spin+structures+and+quadratic+enhancements+of+the+intersection+form+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJ1C7Oli7OmCSPmgAcAB4AIABUIgBUJIBATGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis8smYhaHtAhUPTDABHa6OBlIQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), there are many papers discussing the issue.

- What are the relations and basic intuitions between the quadratic enhancements of the intersection form and **spin structures**?
- What about the $pin^{\pm}$ structures**?
- are there non-quadratic enhancements? Like cubic or quartic? How?